# Object in method leaks

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite, memory-management, memory-leaks

there's another leak issue. I've a method:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)returnItems:(int)nominalID subCountryID:(int)subCountryID
{
NSArray *paths =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path =
[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

NSMutableArray *itemsArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];

if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sqlItems=sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT itm.itemID,itm.itemYear,itm.rarity,itm.mintage,iaval.availability as avalibility,iaval.quality as quality,itm.Mintmark,itm.specialRemark,iaval.dated\
                                         from items as itm\
                                         inner join itemAvailability as iaval on itm.itemID=iaval.itemID\
                                         INNER join NominalsAndSubcountriesRelation as nasr on nasr.nominalID=itm.relatedToNominal\
                                         WHERE nasr.nominalID=%i AND nasr.subCountryID=%i",nominalID,subCountryID);

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlItems, -1, &statement, NULL);
if ( sqlResult== SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        Item *item=[[Item alloc]init];
        item.itemID=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        char *itemYear=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        item.rarity=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);
        char *mintage=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
        item.availability=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
        item.quality=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 5);
        char *mintmark=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6);
        char *specialRemark=(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7);
        char *dated=(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8);
        item.itemYear=(itemYear)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:itemYear]:@"";
        item.mintage=(mintage)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:mintage]:@"Unknown";
        item.mintmark=(mintmark)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:mintmark]:@"";
        item.specialRemark=(specialRemark)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:specialRemark]:@"";
        item.dated=(dated)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dated]:@"";
        [itemsArray addObject:item];
        [item release];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_free((char*)sqlItems);
}
}
else
{
    [self dbConnectionError];
}

    return itemsArray;
}
```

The instruments tool claims that there's 100% leak on item object. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing appears to be wrong in the code you present; `item` is released after being added to `itemsArray` and `itemsArray` is autoreleased, so returned as a non-owning reference.

You should therefore assume that whoever receives `itemsArray` is retaining it and failing to release it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any leaks in this code.

Instruments tells you which object is being leaked and where it was allocated. That allocation is not necessarily where it's being leaked.

So: Where are you using items from that array? Somewhere, you're retaining an item from the array without releasing it. (Or, possibly, the entire array.)